# How to compare properties in spring data jpa @Query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I try to compare the property ,but it is the class and in the query

```
@Query("select a from ApplyOfIP as a left join a.state where a.state = :state")
```

It will compare the state.id,But i want to compare the state's properties

```
 @Query("select a from ApplyOfIP as a left join a.state where a.state = :state " +
        "and a.applicant.department like %:department% " +
        "and (a.finallyIPName like %:ipName% or a.applyInfo.applyIPName like %:ipName%) " +
        "and a.applicant.name like %:applicantName%")
Page<ApplyOfIP> findApplyOfIPSWithState(
        @Param("page") Pageable pageable, @Param("state") State state
        , @Param("department") String department, @Param("ipName") String ipName
        , @Param("applicantName") String applicantName);
```

Comment: Then do it: `where a.state.foo = :foo and a.state.bar = :bar`

Comment: if i do this way the param is to much